# EditText.setFocusable(false); can't be set to true. :/

Tags: java, android

A very strange situation, I've got this code that is supposed to make an EditText filed uneditable if SpnSelected.equals("Service") and editable again, if its something else.

```
final EditText etAdd = (EditText)dialogAddTextView.findViewById(R.id.etSymb);

    if ( SpnSelected.equals("Service") )
    {
        etAdd.setFocusable(false);
        TextView tvInfo = (TextView)dialogAddTextView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddTextInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        etAdd.setFocusable(true);
        TextView tvInfo = (TextView)dialogAddTextView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddTextInfo);
    }
```

It does make it uneditable ok, but it doesn't bring the ability to edit back with etAdd.setFocusable(true);

Any ideas what to do about it? Thanks! :)

Comment: wouldn't `setEnabled(true/false)` be more appropriate?

Comment: works. only it makes the textedit kinda gray, as if its disables. therefor setFocusable would be more preferable, only it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Try

```
etAdd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
etAdd.setFocusable(true);
```

instead of just

```
etAdd.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: According to the documentation for `.setFocusableInTouchMode()` calling `.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` makes calling `.setFocusable(true)` unnecessary. I.e. you only need to call `etAdd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: Yes. it did the work. But when calling .setFocusableInTouchMode(true) alone it works very well. So .setFocusable(true) is redundant. Please update the answer

Answer (score 3):

I use below code focus and click remove and add:

Remove:
`secondFirstHalfEditText.setClickable(false);
 secondFirstHalfEditText.setFocusable(false);`

Add :

```
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setFocusable(true);
```

Must use this For active Edittext >>

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Its working for me perfecly

Answer (score 2):

This solution has worked for me :

```
 EditText test3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 CheckBox check1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 test3.setClickable(false);
 test3.setEnabled(false);
 test3.setFocusable(false);
 check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      if(check1.isChecked()){
         test3.setText("");
         test3.setClickable(false);
         test3.setEnabled(false);
         test3.setFocusable(false);
      } else {
         test3.setClickable(true);
         test3.setEnabled(true);
         test3.setFocusable(true);
         test3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      }
    }
 });
```

After i check the checkbox the edittext is disabled.

i hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

my code work well using `editText.requestFocus();`

Answer (score -2):

You have to set the EditText to

```
etAdd.setEnabled(false);
```